# Nested anchor tag within h3 in scalatags

Tags: html, scala, scalatags

Im trying to generate the following HTML from scalatags:

```
<h3>There were orders found in <a href="#somewhere">somewhere </a> and <a href="#somewhereelse">somewhere else </a> </h3>
```

So far my attempt using the following in scalatags has not worked:

```
h3("There were orders found in" + a(href:="#somewhere")("somewhere") + "and" + a(href:="#somewhereelse")("somewhere else"))
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Why are you using currying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h3("There were orders found in ", a(href:="#somewhere", "somewhere"), 
    " and ", a(href:="#somewhereelse", "somewhere else"))
```

This is how the structure would be in XML:

```
- <h3>
  - TEXT
  - <a>
    - TEXT
  - TEXT
  - <a>
    - TEXT
```

If you try and stick to writing your scalatags code the same way it would be structured in XML, it should come out OK. Also remember that in scalatags you intersperse attributse (`... := ...`) and children; scalatags figures out which is which.

Comment: this ended up making the most sense to me. Thinking of it like XML helped a ton.